# Can you re-write a line of code in a file using enumerate in python?

Tags: python, file-io

I've got a large file that I need to write to so I don't want to open it entirely in my memory so I'm trying to rewrite it using enumerate. I can find the line of code I need and print it but I'm having trouble re-writing the code.

the code to print the line of code I want:

```
with open('test2.py', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 4:
            print line
```

the code to re-write that line that makes sense to me but is incorrect:

```
with open('test2.py', 'r+') as f:
    it = '2'
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 4:
            if line != it:
                f.write(line)
```

I get no error

Comment: You want to replace the 5th line of file with '2'?

Comment: @f.rodrigues I just tried this and it didn't work, can you explain the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got, you weren't far off. Don't use Fileinput to solve this, that is just for working with multiple files; and Bens code is wrong anyway.

```
with open('test2.py', 'r+') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 4:
            line = '2'
            f.write(line)
            print line
```